# Converting statements to set notions

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Having trouble with this problem. These are the sets.

S: set of all students

F: set of all female students

M: set of all male students

H: set of all happy students

L: set of all students that have less than 75%

Questions:

a. Students that are happy and do not have more than 75% are female

b. Students with more than 75% are male and happy

c. For a female student to be happy she must have over 75%

d. No students have more than 75% and are not happy

This is what I got:

a) $(H \cap L) \subseteq F$

b) $(M \cap H) \subseteq \overline{L}$

c) $(F \cap H) \subseteq \overline{L}$

d) $(S \cap (\overline{L} \cap \overline{H})) = \emptyset$

Comment: Are there any students that have *exactly* (not more and not less) 75%?

Comment: @drhab Going by each statement in the question it is either more or less, so no.

Comment: Not being mentioned in any statement does not guarantee non-existence. It should at least be mentioned that "less than 75%" and "more than 75%" are supposed to be complements in this context.

Comment: @drhab the L set is students that have less than 75%. And no questions ask if it was just 75% so i dont see how that would be a problem

Comment: In your answer on a) you identify the students that do not have more than 75% with students that have less than 75%. That is illegal unless it is certain that no studenst exist having exactly 75%.

Comment: Your answer on b) says that students that are male and happy have at least 75%.

Comment: @drhab okay I understand what you are saying. I believe the questions are implied to greater or under not exactly equal to 75%